# Porque no puedo instalar ldap en mi proyecto con el pip desde el pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
 File "/tmp/pip-install-2m0e5s64/ldap/setup.py", line 19, in run
    '"ldap" is not installable. You probably want python-ldap.'
ValueError: "ldap" is not installable. You probably want python-ldap.
```

Command

```
"/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-2m0e5s64/ldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-9wz6co8k/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/include/site/python3.6/ldap" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-2m0e5s64/ldap/
```

Comment: Son dependencias de desarrollo veo que estas usando ubuntu trata con: ```sudo apt-get install python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
 sudo pip install python-ldap ```